# Find the % of the used memory in impala

Tags: impala

How can I see the memory % that is used right now in Impala?
Also I want to check the whole memory size

Answer (score 0):

Best idea would be to use `cloudera manager`.
It shows health of impala. Queries running, which query taking more memory and kill them if needed.
Manage/distribute the memory between yarn, impala as well.
I am not sure about licensing and probably its not free but you can ask your CDH administrator.
Here is few screenshots from sample system -
Health -
[image: Health]
CDH Manager view -
[image: CDH Manager view]
Running Impala Queries(shows GB, duration) -
[image: Running Impala Queries]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I know cloudera manager and how to monitor it but I want to know if it is any option to see exactly the % of the memory

Comment: are you looking for real time monitoring tool?

Comment: Yes. I am running a lot of queries and sometimes some of them failed. I want to monitor why this happens and if any of these queries reserves a lot of memory.

Comment: i think that can be easily checked from `cloudera manager`. Go to `clusters > impala queries` to see running qries in real time. It will also show row count + GB consumed by that SQL. I Know its not a very good log but you should be able to identify sql that consuming lot of GB or processing lots of rows.